# How do I write a character in the android bluetooth communication?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm writing an android program where I need to send one character to another bluetooth device. I have written this piece of the program, but when you send the character, I do not know what is the function that I use. In the program, the party is in doubt with points interrogations.

---

```
package com.example.bl;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.*;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bot1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bot1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    // Device does not support Bluetooth
                }   

                int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }

            //  ??????
            //  ??????
            //  ??????
            //  ??????  




                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new
                        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        dialogo.setTitle("Aviso");
                        dialogo.setMessage("Foi!");
                        dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                        dialogo.show();
                        }
                        });             
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First refer this page Bluetooth, from [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Use `android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket` to establish connection

To create a BluetoothSocket for connecting to a known device, use `BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord().` 
Then call `connect()` to attempt a connection to the remote device. This call will block until a connection is established or the connection fails.

Comment: Thanks!

I have not experience on programing in java, so, even you telling me this, I have not idea where put the missing parts. The name of the device is autocom, and the passaword is 1988. Could you please give me an example?

 Very thanks!

 Rafael Kröss

Comment: you  can refer the sample program of BluetoothChat from http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html